# Restrict the special characters in the given regex

Tags: c#, regex

Following is my regular Expression:

```
^[a-z0-9](?!.*?[^\na-z0-9]{2}).*?[a-z0-9]@gmail.com
```

which accept `-` and `_` but not consecutively, I want to restrict it for `[$%&(){}!]`, which is not happening please provide a solution for the same.

given regular expression allowed:

1. abc-d@gmail.com
2. a-b_c@gmail.com
3. abc$d@gmail.com

   3) is not valid. Expression should not accept `$,&,%,!,{,},(,).*` in gmail address

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Add more details to your question. Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Provide more details with examples that how it works and in which case it doesn't, so that requirement is clear

Answer (score 1):

Despite the very vague and confusing question, I think the regex you are looking for is as follows.

```
^[^`~!@#$%^&*()+={}\[\]|\\:;“’<>?๐฿]*$
```

This will return true for any string that does not contain those characters

Answer (score 1):

`.*?` is probably what is causing you problems. It will match nothing, up to everything, but as little as is required to get a match. But there's no restriction on what characters it will accept (`.` matches anything).

> Expression should not accept `$,&,%,!,{,},(,).*` in gmail address

Then you'll want something like `(?![$&%!{}()*])` in your regex. This is a non capturing negative lookahead that will assert none of the characters listed are found.

> which accept `-` and `_` but not consecutively

You can add the `-` and `_` to the accepting regex, and check for duplicates separately. Assuming an email address in `emailAddress`, something like

```
var validation = "^(?![$&%!{}()*])[a-z0-9_-]+@gmail.com";
var containsDuplicates = emailAddress.IndexOf("--") > -1 && emailAddress.IndexOf("__") > -1;
var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, validation) && !containsDuplicates;
```

Now, this will fail on valid gmail addresses, such as those containing one or more periods, but that seems like a separate issue.